# Physionet.org - Sepsis Data Files?

Tags: data-request, medical, mimic-iii

I am searching for "Pre" and "Post" Physiological Data Files from Patients that have Sepsis. They can be in just about any format such as Excel, CSV, etc. but contain a Time Stamp, Heart Rate, BP(s), Temperature, Respiratory Rate, etc.

Comment: This is probably something you will have to derive yourself, and will depend on how you define "sepsis."